# YQL JSON Response back to html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, yql

I am trying to find a way to take JSON returned from YQL and parse it back to html with javascript(or angularJS)

**Example JSON:**

```
    {
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2015-09-22T21:23:55Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "3",
     "execution-stop-time": "383",
     "execution-time": "380",
     "content": "http://www.google.com/"
    }
   ],
   "user-time": "758",
   "service-time": "1870",
   "build-version": "0.2.509"
  },
  "results": {
   "div": {
    "class": "news-detail",
    "article": {
     "class": "news-entry",
     "div": {
      "class": "news-content",
      "p": [
       "Lorem ipsum",
       {
        "a": {
         "href": "http://google.com/",
         "u": "Click Here"
        },
        "content": " "
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Ideally i'd like to take the set from the result and convert it back to html

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<div class="news-detail">
    <article class="news-entry">
        <div class="news-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum <a href="http://google.com">Click here</a>
            </p>
        </div>        
    </article>
</div>
```

The problem is that HTML is dynamic, so the structure does not remain the same.  Otherwise I would just have gotten the values and inserted them to their proper spots.  Has anyone tried doing this before?

Comment: do some research into recursive functions. Will need to check `typeof` at each level and react accordingly

Comment: That was actually the direction I planned on heading if there wasn't an alternative.  Seeing if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: nope....you have to walk down each level. Or use a different scraper that will return html

Comment: Ya I was thinking of just switching it back over to XML, and grabbing the node with the html I want.

Comment: Was just thinking... i bet there's a library already around for parsing yql like this. I've even written one myself years ago but have no idea where it is now